# How to create a rotating view in Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, view

How to create a rotating view in Android using Kotlin? (Like a fidget spinner :))
For example, after a button is clicked an ImageView will spin until the other button is clicked.

Do you have any ideas for this?

Comment: what did you try?